# I'm trying to write a batch command to automatically run VSCode in a workspace but when I close the CMD, VSCode shuts down too

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, cmd

I wrote a batch file with the intention of launching Opera and VSCode (on a workspace) with one click, it looks like this:

[image: Batch file screen shot]

It runs just fine. Opera starts, then VSCode does as well. The problem is, that when I close the CMD window, VSCode also shuts itself down. I wanted the CMD window to automatically close after execution in the first place, so I tried putting an "&& exit" and "exit" at the end of the code  (not at the same time), but it didn't work.

Comment: `Start` VSCode too!

Comment: What's the point in providing textual code as image?

Comment: @Compo I tried `start code .` and `start code -r .` (that opens it in the most recently used window), but both start VSCode in the main menu, not in the folder that I I'm currently working. That's why I saved a workspace and set it to be opened in the batch file.

Comment: @aschipfl Is it wrong?

Comment: Well, [yes](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the info, it was useful:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have opera.exe added to the PATH.

```
@echo off

start opera
cd C:\Users\louis\Desktop\Development\Projects\JS
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" JS.code-workspace
```

or

```
@echo off

start opera
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" C:\Users\louis\Desktop\Development\Projects\JS\JS.code-workspace
```